# Use self as parameter in a singleton

Tags: objective-c, singleton, self

I have the following method-header in a singleton:

```
-(int) reconnectToServerForClass:(id)myClass
```

The parameter myClass is always the self-object of the calling class. Different ViewControllers in my project call this method so my question is this:

Is it possible to access myClass.view or what can I do to achieve that?

---

my intention is that I want to show a progress-hud for every ViewController that calls the method:

```
MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:myClass.view animated:YES];
```

Isn't there the need for casting myClass before I can access the view-property?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you are doing in this method but yeah we can access any public property of the class with it's object.

Comment: Would you be able to share more of your code? I'm having trouble understanding what you're asking. Header files and example usage of the reconnectToServerForClass: method with your classes would be nice.

Comment: If you know myClass is a instance of UIViewController or subclass of that why don't you change the signature of the method to '-(int)reconnectToServerForClass:(UIViewController)viewController' if thats not a option remember that 'id' is assignable to any type i.e. 'UIViewController *viewController = myClass;' would work fine.

Comment: That's a real good question ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly you can do the following:

```
-(int) reconnectToServerForClass:(UIViewController *)myClass
{
    //myClass.view
}
```

or inside the method

```
-(int) reconnectToServerForClass:(id)myClass
{
    if([myClass isKindOfClass:[UIViewController class]])
    {
        UIViewController *viewController = myClass; //edit as suggested by Peter Segerblom
        //viewController.view
    }
}
```

Which ever option you choose is that it will depend on how you use it and how you want to manage or limit the callers, in option 1 the parameter must be a sub class of `UIViewController` and the same for option 2 but the difference is that you can pass in anything but if the type is not `UIViewController` it will just do nothing.

Disclaimer: This code is not tested and typed from memory, so it might not compile, let me know if you come across issues and I will edit answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

If you want to access it from the singleton class, you make a member or property of which is a pointer to a view, then set that in reconnectToServerForClass: and access it as you would any other member.

If you want to access it from outside, you do the same, and do something like [[MySingleton instance] view]

Be aware that dragons lie ahead of your path, you will need to make sure that views "unset" this property before they are destroyed, otherwise your singleton might try to access a no-longer-existing view instance.